# Why isn't sudo -H setting the HOME variable?

Tags: sudo

I've just started using Manjaro (based on Arch Linux) and I've run into an interesting thing:

```
$ sudo env | grep HOME
HOME=/root
$ sudo -H env | grep HOME
HOME=/root
```

I've looked at the man page for `sudo` and checked to make sure that my home directory is in fact correctly set in `/etc/passwd`. Based on my understanding, the output for the second of the above commands *should* be `/home/laurence`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The man page for `sudo` writes,

> **`-H, --set-home`**
>                    Request that the security policy set the `HOME` environment variable to the home directory
>                    specified by the target user's password database entry.  Depending on the policy, this may
>                    be the default behavior.

The key here is that `-H` sets the *target user's* home directory. When you call `sudo env` the target user is inferred to be `root`. (If you used something like `sudo -u john -H env` you would get the home directory for `john`.)